# Can I use Symfony new to create a console-only project?

Tags: symfony-console

Instead of starting a project via `symfony new <prj_name>`, I used `composer require symfony/console`. I am unable to access any of the generate commands.

Am I going about this incorrectly? If I use `composer require` how do I automate the creation of the initial bin/console?

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/command-line-php-using-symfony-console/

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console.html

Answer (score 0):

So in the *existing project* that I started using only `composer require symfony/console` and had to manually create the console.php file, I did the following:

Require the Sensio Bundle:

```
$ composer require sensio/generator-bundle
```

Then, in console.php, require the [Sensio Bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/sensio/generator-bundle)

```
.
.
.
use Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Command\GenerateCommandCommand;
.
.
.
$console->add(new GenerateCommandCommand());
```

Now when I run the console.php file, the help text shows a link to that command.

```
$ php console.php 
Console Tool

Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Options:
  -h, --help            Display this help message
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi            Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Available commands:
  help              Displays help for a command
  list              Lists commands
 generate
  generate:command  Generates a console command
```